# Whats wrong in this SPF syntax?

Tags: dns, spf

I am not very familiar with SPF records so I need a bit of help setting up my SPF record correctly.

Below is a record I created using online  tutorials

***v=spf1 a mx ip4:192.186.236.104 include:_spf.google.com include:bmsend.com include:postbox.pidatacenters.com ~all***

when i check in http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf%3apidatacenters.com%3a192.186.236.104&run=toolpage#

it shows everything is right

fraudmarc.com/spf-record-check/

in this website it shows an error like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecblr.png)

Give me the solutions

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things wrong here. The definitive SPF checker is [Scott Kitterman's](http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html). It finds this error:

```
PermError SPF Permanent Error: Unknown mechanism found: postbox.pidatacenters.com
```

It's not clear why this is presented as this particular error because the syntax itself is valid, but you have a recursive definition - your SPF includes `postbox.pidatacenters.com`, but the SPF for that domain includes itself, which makes no sense. It also contains the google SPF, so you don't need to include that again.

I suggest you set your SPF records to these. For `pidatacenters.com`:

```
v=spf1 ip4:192.186.236.104 mx include:bmsend.com include:postbox.pidatacenters.com ~all
```

you don't need the `a` clause in there because it resolves to the same IP as you already listed. It's polite to put `ip` clauses first as they are fastest to resolve for receivers, as they do not require DNS lookups.

For `postbox.pidatacenters.com`:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

Comment: I get errors for these? 2 errors detected
Invalid value in "include" element
Unknown "_spf.google.com" element is detected

Comment: It's correct according to the validator and also matches exactly what's in [Google's own docs](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F10684623%3Fhl%3Den&assistant_id=generic-unu&product_context=10684623&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a). Are you sure you've not got a stray space in there or something?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your getting the syntax error with that test is because any valid syntax checker authenticates the entire SPF Statement. Which means it has to test the SPF records of every included statement.

When it checks the include for "postbox.pidatacenters.com" in the SPF syntax for pidatacenters.com, it will see this.

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com postbox.pidatacenters.com ~all
```

Which is invalid.

Anyway, you should follow Synchro's Advice and change the records to what he stated.

Also testing with the site Synchro recommended is fine, but it relies on a lot of expert knowledge you might not have. You might think you're emailing one way, but you're really not.

It's better to get a real live example using a reflector, just send an email to each of these and you'll get results back telling you if the SPF is correct, I always use multiple reflectors, to ensure things are accurate.

```
 mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com
 check-auth@verifier.port25.com
```